# VSCode Extension button over editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to create a button that is placed over my text editor like the "Add configuration..." button. I could not find any documentation in the oficial docs.

https://i0.wp.com/www.alphr.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/JS12.png?w=700&ssl=1

This is what I want to accomplish but with custom text when my extension is actived. Or at least create a new bar over the panel so I can place my button there.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot where exactly you would like to place your button in VS Code?

Comment: Sure! I can't post images yet, that's why I haven't done it before.

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKgED.png) the location where you want to position your button?

Comment: Noup, thats an action button. I posted an example in the question. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that embedding a button into the editor is not possible, since the extension API does not provide a contribution point for this to be implemented. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91082)'s a related feature request on VS Code's GitHub repository.